# Tiff Analyzer

Tags: analysis, tiff

I am writing a program to convert some data, mainly a bunch of Tiff images.  Some of the Tiffs seems to have a minor problem with them.  They show up fine in some viewers (Irfanview, client's old system) but not in others (Client's new system, Window's picture and fax viewer).  I have manually looked at the binary data and all the tags seem ok.  Can anyone recommend an app that can analyze it and tell me what, if anything, is wrong with it?

Also, for clarity sake, I'm only converting the data about the images which is stored seperately in a database and copying the images, I'm not editting the images myself, so I'm pretty sure I'm not messing them up.

**UDPATE:**
For anyone interested, here are the tags from a good and bad file:

BAD
Tag                       Type   Length   Value
256 Image Width           SHORT    1      1652
257 Image Length          SHORT    1      704
258 Bits Per Sample       SHORT    1      1
259 Compression           SHORT    1      4
262 Photometric           SHORT    1      0
266 Fill Order            SHORT    1      1
273 Strip Offsets         LONG     1      210      (d2 Hex)
274 Orientation           SHORT    1      3
277 Samples Per Pixel     SHORT    1      1
278 Rows Per Strip        SHORT    1      450
279 Strip Byte Counts     LONG     1      7264     (1c60 Hex)
282 X Resolution          RATIONAL 1      <194>    200 / 1 = 200.000
283 Y Resolution          RATIONAL 1      <202>    200 / 1 = 200.000
284 Planar Configuration  SHORT    1      1
296 Resolution Unit       SHORT    1      2

Good
Tag                       Type   Length   Value
254 New Subfile Type      LONG     1      0        (0 Hex)
256 Image Width           SHORT    1      1193
257 Image Length          SHORT    1      788
258 Bits Per Sample       SHORT    1      1
259 Compression           SHORT    1      4
262 Photometric           SHORT    1      0
266 Fill Order            SHORT    1      1
270 Image Description     ASCII    45     256
273 Strip Offsets         LONG     1      1118     (45e Hex)
274 Orientation           SHORT    1      1
277 Samples Per Pixel     SHORT    1      1
278 Rows Per Strip        LONG     1      788      (314 Hex)
279 Strip Byte Counts     LONG     1      496      (1f0 Hex)
280 Min Sample Value      SHORT    1      0
281 Max Sample Value      SHORT    1      1
282 X Resolution          RATIONAL 1      <301>    200 / 1 = 200.000
283 Y Resolution          RATIONAL 1      <309>    200 / 1 = 200.000
284 Planar Configuration  SHORT    1      1
293 Group 4 Options       LONG     1      0        (0 Hex)
296 Resolution Unit       SHORT    1      2

Answer (score 3):

Usually that's because the tiff is using the JPEG encoding from the 6.0 standard, which was abandoned shortly afterward. Look at tag 259. If it is 6, that is the problem. JPEGs should be encoded with the "newer" scheme, 7. Standard libraries will not read the old one, including the ones that come with Windows.

You can use libtiff (or any of the libraries or programs that use libtiff, most of them do) to read these, but scheme 6 (OJPEG) is deliberately disabled by default in libtiff. You will have to patch and recompile libtiff to enable it. [Here's a link with instructions](http://www.asmail.be/msg0055095784.html).

Comment: Tag 259 is 4 (adding words to meet minimum comment length requirement...sigh)

Comment: Is the width of the image on the problematic ones divisible by 8? Group 4 compression is supposed to support it, but not everyone does...

Comment: That's odd. For the bad image, the origin is the lower right-hand corner, but that's usually ignored. Also, the good image is in a single strip, but the bad one is in two. Is there a second 273 tag in the bad image?

Comment: No, there is not a second 273 tag

Comment: Well, if the image length is 704, and the rows per strip is 450, there should be a second strip, and a second 273 giving an offset to it, right? When IrfanView (love that program) displays it, how many rows is it showing?

Answer (score 1):

[LibTIFF](http://www.libtiff.org/) might be helpful. Problems viewing Tiff's are often caused by the compression used. I'd look into that.

Answer (score 1):

The RowsPerStrip in the bad image is 450, which is less than 704, the image length (height). This implies the image must have two strips. Because of this, StripOffsets and StripByteCounts must both have a count of two. These indicates the file offsets where the strip data is located. When these offsets are missing, only the first strip will be decodeable.

Answer (score 0):

Worth giving ImageMagick a go. My understanding is that TIFF is a rather complex file format, and that not everyone implements the format fully.

Answer (score 0):

TIFF is a very complex format - not only in the richness of the data it can encode (various pixel format, various encoders) - but also because of the richness of the file format itself (its a general structure that can hold anything). It's basically trash dump for every idea we've ever had in imaging. :-)

I would highly recommend the WPF Imaging library from .NET 3.0. Its Tiff decoder, while not supporting all pixel formats, it very robust and has an easy interface for accessing all the meta data.